Connecting to a TCP socket on the android emulator from another device on the same LAN
I'm developing an android app in kotlin where I have two instances of the app:

In the android emulator of android studio on my PC (win11)
On my actual phone

Both devices are on the same LAN. I make the app open a TCP socket on port 2001 on the emulator, and I try to connect to that socket from the app on my phone using 192.168.18.16:2001 where 192.168.18.16 is my PC's local IP
I've set up port forwarding from my PC to the emulator via abd using:
abd -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:2001 tcp:2001

and I can see the rule listed in:
adb forward --list

Here's the relevant kotlin code that runs on my phone:
import java.net.Socket

// ...

    private val socket: Socket = Socket(ip, port) // ip = "192.168.18.16" and port = 2001
    private val outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()

And here's the code that runs on the emulator:
import java.net.ServerSocket

// ...

    private val serverSocket = ServerSocket(port) // port = 2001
    private val clientSocket: Socket = serverSocket.accept()
    private val inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream()

Now the weird part:
My phone blocks at the Socket(ip, port) line, and my emulator blocks at the serverSocket.accept() line. So far this is normal if we assume my phone can't connect to my PC for some reason. To isolate the problem, I wrote a quick python script that can accept/make TCP connections and I got it to do the following:

Ran a TCP server from python on 2001 on my PC and my phone connected to it just fine. Implication: My PC is not blocking my phone due to firewall
Ran the TCP server component of my app on the emulator, and used python on my PC as a client, and managed to connect to 192.168.18.16:2001. Implication: The adb port forwarding is set up correctly

I suspect that the emulator is only listening on 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0 which is why my PC can reach it, but not my phone. How do I make this work correctly?
